# error in dynamic casting

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I am getting error while dynamic casting the below code.

```
  class CBase
  {
  };

  class CDerived: public CBase
  {
  };



  main()
  {

    CBase b;
    CDerived* pd;
    pd = dynamic_cast<CDerived*>(&b);  
  }
```

The error code is `:error C2683: 'dynamic_cast' : 'CBase' is not a polymorphic type.`

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, what exactly is it you don't understand in it? also note that your main function is lacking the mandatory int return type.

Comment: In your case you can use `static_cast<T>`: `pd = static_cast<CDerived*>(&b);`

Comment: @PlasmaHH, whups!  thought this was c#, my bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` only works with ***polymorphic classes***.
Your base class `CBase` should have ***at least one virtual method***.

Comment: +1:  Even if that virtual method is just a virtual destructor in the base class.

Comment: If your base class has virtual methods it should (probably) also have a virtual destructor. So simplify by adding just a virtual destructor.